# Find all 2x2 matrices with Null space on the line 3x-5y=0

Tags: linear-algebra

I just learned nullspace and I'm not sure how to do this. I figure that  $3\vec{x}-5\vec{y}=\vec{0}$

$\implies$ 3$\begin{bmatrix}x1\\x2\end{bmatrix} - 5\begin{bmatrix}y1\\y2\end{bmatrix} = \vec{0}$

But this only gets me

$\begin{bmatrix}3x1-5y1\\3x2-5y2\end{bmatrix} = \vec{0}$.

The solution online is here: http://www.slader.com/textbook/9781118473504-elementary-linear-algebra-11th-edition/248/exercises/25a/

But given that x and y are different varaibles, I don't understand how the parameters `s` and `t` could be assigned to both the 3 and 5 (eg. $3s-5s=0$ & $3t-5t=0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The null space is
$$
 \mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A} \right) = 
\left\{\,
\left[ \begin{array}{r}
  3 \\ 5
\end{array} \right]
\,\right\}
$$

---

The space has dimension $2$, and the range space vector must be *orthogonal* to the null space
$$
 \mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right) = 
\left\{\,
\left[ \begin{array}{r}
  -5 \\ 3
\end{array} \right]
\,\right\}
$$

---

All row vectors in the matrix are some multiple of the span:
$$
\mathbf{A} =
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  5a & 3a \\
  5b & 3b
\end{array} \right], \qquad a \in\mathbb{C},\  b \in\mathbb{C}
\tag{1}
$$

---

---

[image: vectors]

Cartesian coordinates are the first basis we learn about, in par because of the simplicity. A big contribution to the ease of use is that the coordinates are independent. For example, you can move along a line of constant $y$ and the $x$ coordinate will change, but the $y$ coordinate will not.

This is a consequence on *orthogonality.* A bit part of linear algebra involves finding another set of orthogonal bases, the eigenvector problem.

One view of matrices is through the fundamental subspaces, through decomposition into a range space and its orthogonal complement, the null space. We know then, automatically, that if we have a range space vector, any perpendicular vector is in the null space. And in this problem, when we have a null space vector, we know that every perpendicular vector is in the range space.

Now the task is to find that perpendicular vector...

---

What vectors are perpendicular to the line 
$$
 3x - 5y = 0 
\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad
5y = 3x
\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad
y = \frac{3}{5} x?
$$
(Thanks @Nick.)

**Method 1: slope**

The slope of this line is
$$
 m = \frac{3}{5}.
$$
The slope of the perpendicular lines is
$$
 m_{\perp} = -\frac{1}{m} = -\frac{5}{3},
$$
or
$$
  y_{\perp} = -\frac{5}{3} x 
\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad
 3y_{\perp} = -5x
\tag{2}
$$

**Method 2: vectors**

What are the vectors perpendicular to the vector $\left[ \begin{array}{r}
  3 \\ 5
\end{array} \right]$? Recall that two vectors are perpendicular when theor dot product vanishes.
$$ 
  u \perp v \qquad \iff \qquad u\cdot v = 0
$$
Solve the vector equation
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{r}
  \alpha \\ \beta
\end{array} \right]
\cdot
\left[ \begin{array}{r}
  3 \\ 5
\end{array} \right] =
3\alpha + 5\beta = 0
$$
There are an infinite number of solutions for this problem:
$$
 \alpha = -\frac{5}{3} \beta
$$
Simplest solution is to let $\beta = 1$; that solution vector is 
$\left[ \begin{array}{r}
  -5 \\ 3
\end{array} \right]$. This is the blue vector in the figure above.

Comment: I don't understand the range space vector concept -- we haven't learned it. I'm open to the idea, but I'm trying to understand using the concepts we are covering in class. If I have 3x-5y=0 as the span of my null space, this means all solutions fall on that line. Meaning the null space as a matrix is `[ [3,-5], [3,-5] ]` (I would put it only once, but I guess being in 2x2 means it needs to be listed twice for the second dimension?). From there, I'm not sure how one goes about adding in the parameters. Honestly the intuition isn't there and I'm struggling to understand what's going on.

Comment: @Alex G: We all struggled at first. Thanks for the feedback. An update will follow. Hang in there.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I realize now that my idea of the nullspace was wrong, but I see now why it should be [3,-5] like you say at the top of your answer. Also I understand how you go about finding the solution now. But the one thing I am not getting is the connection between the null space and the perpendicular vector. Why is the solution we are looking for going to be parallel? You start by asking "What vectors are perpendicular...?" but I don't understand why we are looking for perpendicular vectors in the first place.

Comment: $5x - 3y = 0 \Rightarrow y = +\frac{3}{5}x$ so you got the wrong slope for the line and its perpendicular.

Comment: Oh, perpendicular because the solution for the homogeneous Ax=0 is the dot product, so A (dot) x = 0 --> that each component of x is perpendicular to each row vector in A. I forgot that theorem, but now it makes sense.

Comment: @Nick: Double checking now. Thanks for the cross check. Stay tuned.

Comment: D'oh: I meant to say $3x - 5y = 0 \Rightarrow y = +\frac{3}{5}x$ - sorry about the dyslexia.